# Not able to use hot reloading getting error : The packager server has restarted since the last Hot update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, hot-reload

Don't know why but getting this error from yesterday. I was trying to use react-native-debugger and hot reloading at same time and looks like i messed up something. I am attaching snap of error here.[image: This error I am getting when I switch on hot reloading]

I have tried reinstalling all node-modules, closing all shell and restarting again but nothing worked. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Shake the phone > Dev Setting > Disable Js Minify

This solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can shake your phone and disable the "Hot reloading" option.